# RegEx to test if a string contains more than X words

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a regex to test if a test string contains more than X words (precision is not important - we talk about 80 words or so, if it will be 81 or 79 it will be good enough)

My guess is that I have to test if a string has more than X whitespace characters (double spaces etc can be ignored, it is not that important)

Platform is JavaScript, but I need a pure expression, without any code around it (ex. I can not count number of matches with javascript code)

Anyone can help me assemble that kind of expression?

Comment: What programming language/Platform?

Comment: The regex would look like this: ` ` (just a space). We need to know the programming language so we can tell you how to count the number of matches for that ` `.

Comment: Emmad Kareem, it will be used in JavaScript

Comment: @Scott Hunter, have no idea, the docs I found described quantifiers that perform consequemntal search, my inquery is about characters in different places in text..

Comment: What is the definition of a "word"?  Characters separate by white space?  Characters in the set [a-zA-Z]?  Also, some sample data would be good: some strings, and the number of words that are contained in each string.

Comment: @Wayne Conrad, yes, word is a non-breaking sequence of characters separated by whitespaces. You can regard this comment text as an example of a test string :)

In my case it was not important if there are 80 or 81 words, and if they are numbers, characters or what ever, I just needed to find paragraphs of text that are long enough for my project needs. That's why the question was a bit loose.

Comment: @Sych That would all be good information to put in the question itself.  Loose questions tend to end up on hold, as this one did.

Comment: @Wayne Conrad, the accepted answer's author got it perfectly fine, so I am sure the question is expressed okay. But it's up to you to decide.

Comment: @Wayne Conrad, the accepted answer's author got it perfectly fine, so I am sure the question is expressed okay.

Besides, everything that I wrote in the explanation for you IS in the question text itself (just instead of "any text" it says "test string", which is: any non-binary string). 
Definition of a "word" in RegEx is COMMONLY known as: a string that consists of "word characters", which are, characters that can be used to form words. This should not require any extra explanation.

For your consideration, anyway, since I have got a perfect answer from pobrelkey, and I am fully satisfied.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To match a string containing eighty "words" (i.e. unbroken runs of `\w`'s) exactly:

```
/^\W*(\w+\b\W*){80}$/
```

So to match on eighty or more words:

```
/^\W*(\w+\b\W*){80,}$/
```